# json calling item in angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular

i have a json list like this

```
 pray = [
  {
      0: [{
          "Date": 1,
          "Fajr": "05:19 AM",
          Sunrise: "06:50 AM",
          "Dhuhar": "11:59 AM",
          "Asr": "02:47 PM",
          "Maghrib": "05:06 PM",
          "Isha": "06:29 PM"
      },]}]
```

and i want to call an item in month on day at certain time 
so i wrote this

```
 prayf(thing) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
      if (this.items[i].name.toLowerCase() === 'صلاة') {
          console.log('y');
          this.removethings(thing);
          var monthm = new Date().getMonth();
          var day = new Date().getDay();
          var key = Object.keys
          this.things.push({
              name: 'الصلاة الساعة' + ' ' +this.pray[ monthm[key[day].Sunrise] ] + ''
          });
          return true;
      };
  }
  return false;
}
```

but it is not working
saying that sunrise is not defined

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: it does not send an error message but after the function work it say that sunrise is not defined  even if it is written into the json list

Comment: Where in your code do you observe this, can you point it out with a comment or something?